# Cocoa/iPhone: How do I create a Simplified Chinese localization of my app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode, localization, internationalization

I'm in the middle of localizing my iPhone app, and I've gotten English, French, German and Japanese localizations working without any problems. Now I'm trying to get a simplified chinese localization working, and no matter what I try, the chinese .lproj bundle just won't be used when I have the phone set to simplified chinese.

One problem is that I'm not sure what the localization should be called. I've tried "Chinese", zh-Hans, zh-CN, zh_Hans, zh_CN and none of them work. I've even gone as far as digging around inside Remember The Milk's app bundle to see what they used. They're using zh_CN but that doesn't work for me.

Am I missing something obvious here? Do I need to update some plist somewhere? As far as I can see from reading the I18N documentation and looking at the relevant WWDC session video, all I should need to do is make sure I have the right .lproj bundle in my app bundle and I should be good to go... right?

If you think it would help, I can provide a test xcode project that demonstrates the problem...

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's zh_CN for Simp. Chinese (简体中文), zh_TW for Trad. Chinese (繁體中文).

If you are testing **zh_CN.lproj** under **Trad. Chinese** Language setting, it won't work. Just make sure you are testing your app with correct system language setting. Also, the Localizable.strings should be encoded with UTF-16 encoding.

***Update***:
In latest [Localization Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html), these had been changed to **zh-Hans** and **zh-Hant**.

> Particularly in Chinese dialects, a region code is not always the best way to specify the proper dialect or script. For example, traditional Chinese (Han) is the default language spoken in Taiwan and is identified by the code zh_TW in Mac OS X v10.3.9 and earlier. However, traditional Chinese is also commonly spoken in Hong Kong and Macao, which means the zh_TW designator is not entirely accurate in those locations. The new standard defines new tags for the traditional Chinese (Hant) and simplified Chinese (Hans) scripts. Thus, traditional Chinese spoken in any country uses the code zh-Hant. Traditional Chinese, as it is spoken in Taiwan, now uses the locale code zh-Hant_TW.

Comment: Sorry i had a typo in my post, I meant to say zh_CN... I've tried zh_CN and it's not working for me.

Comment: Mike, zh_CN only works with your iPhone's "简体中文" (Simp. Chinese) Language settings (not "繁體中文", Trad. Chinese).

Comment: Don't ask me why, but zh_CN is working now... had to do a clean build and restart of the simulator a few times. Thanks digdog!

Comment: I think in Xcode4 now use 'zh-hans' or 'zh-hant' for Simplified Chinese and Traditional Chinese.

Comment: Yes, it's described in latest I18N Programming Guide: Language and Locale ID section (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002144-BBCEGGFF)

Comment: Seems like there is a bug with the simulator - but not the device - where it picks up the wrong files. So if you set simplified Chinese on the language settings it will pick up the traditional (zh_Hant) files, and vice versa with the simplified (zh_Hans) files.

Comment: zh_Hant and zh_Hans are incorrect, they are actually zh-Hans and zh-Hant.  The hyphen (-) suffix is for dialects, the underscore (_) is used for region codes.

Answer (score 1):

Since iPhone likes to cache resources, you should clean up your app project and re-build it. Then everything will work fine with your localization.

Answer (score 0):

when u add localization for any language other than Chinese
u named as Arabic,German,e.t.c but for the chinese u have to restrict when naming because there are 2 chinese (simple and tradition) so in iphone localization u must named zh_CN(for simplified chinese)
if u placed other name it could not translate 
so b carefull
name must be

zh_CN    (for simplified chinese).

it resolves ur problem
:)

Answer (score 0):

As digdog said above: "Also, the Localizable.strings should be encoded with UTF-16 encoding."

I found UTF-8 for Localizable.strings is alright too, I successfully made several language include zh_CN

I was guided by following post:
http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/277415-localization-strings-in-utf16-vs-utf8.html

Comment: I'm trying both UTF8 and UTF 16, I tried all UTF options in Sublime Text 2 for mac, but XCode keeps telling me it's not in the correct format, can you help me? thanks